# A date field attached to a datepicker and html.validationmessagefor is not activating the validation script

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio

I can't seem to find this answer.  No one is using a combination of javascript, json, VS 2017, and vb.net.  I have a date field on a web screen that has a date picker attached to it.  I have all the coding for the date picker to work, but if the user manually changes the date field... the validator doesn't activate.

this is the code on my View:

```
<strong>Remark Date</strong>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.RemarkDate, "Remark date should be between 5 years in the past and 1 year in the future", New With {.onchange = "RemarkDate(this.value)"})
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.RemarkDate)
```

This is the javascript in the view:

```
var today = new Date();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var minYear = yyyy - 5;
    var maxYear = yyyy + 1;
    var yearsRange = minYear.toString() + ':' + maxYear.toString();
    var startDate = minYear + today.getMonth() + 1 + today.getDate();
    var endDate = maxYear + today.getMonth() + 1 + today.getDate();

    $("#RemarkDate").datepicker({
        minDate: "-0D -0M -5Y",
        maxDate: "-0D -0M +1Y",
        yearRange: yearsRange,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        "defaultDate": new Date(maxYear - 1, 1, 01),
    });

    $("#RemarkDate").datepicker("setDate", today);

    $('#RemarkDate').blur(function () {
        dte = $(this).val();
        var userDate = new date(dte);
        var inputDate = userDate.getFullYear() + userDate.getMonth() + 1 + userDate.getDate();
        result = isValidDateRange(inputDate, startDate, endDate);
        if (result === false) {
            $("#RemarkDate").datepicker("setDate", today);
        }
     });
```

this is the controller after the "Save" button is pressed on the view

```
<HttpPost()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
<HandleError(ExceptionType:=GetType(HttpAntiForgeryException), View:="AccessDenied")>
Public Function AddRemark(<Bind(Exclude:="memberRemark.Member,memberRemark.User")> MemberRemark As MemberRemark)

    If ModelState.IsValid Then

        MemberRemark.SecurityClassification = "FOUO" 'required by STIGs
        db.MemberRemarks.Add(MemberRemark)
        'if the user pressed the save button without changing any of the remark data, this blows up.  Added a Try/Catch
        'block so that it would skip over the error without crashing.
        Try
            db.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Remark Date or Remark Test or both are invalid"
        End Try
    End If

    Return RedirectToAction("Details", New With {.id = MemberRemark.MemberID})
    End Function
```

Comment: I put in the VB.net code, though I'm not sure now if it has any impact on the other coding.

Comment: Well, if it has no impact on the code of concern remove the vb.net tag.